# Firebase functions deploy error with ts syntax errors

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase project that I haven't touched for a while, I modified a view ts files and I wanted to re-deploy my containers, when I try `firebase deploy --only functions` I get a predeploy error with a lot of what seems to be ts syntax errors, here's a sample

```
node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/util.d.ts:1646:17 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1646         set(name: string, value: string): void;
                     ~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/util.d.ts:1646:32 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1646         set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                    ~
```

I installed the latest version of node js and updated my firebase-functions version to the latest wit no success.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the @types/node that you have installed?  Which version of TS are you using?